# How to Update a column is there there is any error while script Execution

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on cleaning the Excel data file, Where i am looking to update the column if the script gets aborted / stops working so i need to update the respective column with the Error message. and move on with the next rows to execute and so on till the last row gets executed.

I have Tried using the for loop on the dataframe (df), But dont understand how to handle the same.

**Input Data:**

```
col1     col2       col3         col4      status

AZBQ225  Rs.1350    23.Apr.2020  235.350
AZBQ2#8     1350    2/5/2020     445.3
AZBQ8"?  Rs.1350    17/06/2020   67.35
336688*     1350    23-01-*?     555.50
AZBQ20@  Rs.1350    23/09/2020   235.39
```

Expected Output:

```
col1     col2       col3         col4      status


AZBQ225    1350    2020-04-23   235.350
AZBQ28     1350    2020-2-5     445.3
AZBQ8      1350    2020-06-17   67.35
336688*    1350    23-01-*?     555.50   AttributeError:'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
AZBQ20     1350    202009-23    235.39
```

**For Eg.** In case Script execution gets aborted on Line No - 5 , So Status Column gets updated with the Error Message.

**Script I am Using:**

```
df = pd.read_excel(open(r'Data'.xlsx', 'rb'), sheet_name='sheet1')

df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
df['col2'] = df['col2'].replace('Rs.', '', regex=True)
df['col3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col3'], errors='coerce')
df['col3'] = df['col3'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['col4'] = df['col4'].round(2)
```

**Please Suggest how to get the respective Error Message in Column "Status", and move on to the Next row to gets executed.**

Comment: you can put `try` and `except` and then put the exception error message in the column. refer [try except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Comment: @simpleApp- By using Try/Except , It will not move on to the next row if there is any error on any line.t will just gets aborted and script execution will going to stop.

Comment: refer this, it will run the loop even though the program got the exception. so execution will not stop.`error_messages=[]
for i in range(2):
    try:
        print(not_defined_variable)
    except Exception as e:
        error_messages.append(e)
        
print(error_messages)`

Comment: @simpleApp -  Can you please share in the Answer section, How to embed the above lines you commented with the code , As not getting how to execute it.

Comment: @simpleApp - Any Suggestions.

Comment: pls accept the answer if you are all set . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the ways, for sure there are other ways too.

1. Build customized functions

```
def replace_w(x):
    result,error=None,None
    try:
        result= x.astype(str).str.replace('\W','')# pls fix this function as it is not working the intend it was suppose too.
    except Exception as e:
        error=e
    return result,error

from datetime import datetime
def format_the_date(d):
    pattern_1=r"[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+" # dd/mm/yyyy
    pattern_2=r"[0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+.[0-9]+" # dd.mmm.yyyy
    result,error=None,None
    if re.match(pattern_1,d):
        try:
            result=datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y'), "%Y-%m-%d")
        except Exception as e:
            error=str(e)
    elif re.match(pattern_2,d):
        try:
            result=datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(d, '%d.%b.%Y'), "%Y-%m-%d")
        except Exception as e:
            print(d,e)
            error=str(e)
    else:
        error="No matching pattern,no transformation!"
        print(error)
    return result,error
```

2. Run the transformation, and append the error on column 'E'

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    r,e=replace_w(row['A'])
    if r:
        df.at[index,'A']=r
    else:
        df.at[index,'E']=str(df.iloc[index]['E']) + "; Col:A,Error-->" + str(e)# concatenate all the errors
        
    df.at[index,'B']= df.iloc[index]['B'].replace('Rs.', '')
    
    r,e=format_the_date(row['C'])
    if r:
        df.at[index,'C']=r
    else:
        df.at[index,'E']=str(df.iloc[index]['E']) + "; Col:C,Error-->" + str(e)# concatenate all the errors
    
    df['D'] = df['D'].round(2)
```

Data setup:

```
raw_data= """
AZBQ225  Rs.1350    23.Apr.2020  235.350 error
AZBQ2#8     1350    2/5/2020     445.3
AZBQ8"?  Rs.1350    17/06/2020   67.35
336688*     1350    23-01-*?     555.50
AZBQ20@  Rs.1350    23/09/2020   235.39
"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
#Data setup
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_data),header=None,delim_whitespace=True,names=('ABCDE'))
```